# References and .dll missing from TFS get latest

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm having an issue related to team foundation server with Visual Studio 2012.
I've checked in a new solution to the server, however when i get latest version for other machines, most of the references are missing and the .dll files in the bin cannot be located. 
Is this because the files are not being pushed when i check in.
Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be checking in dll's and dependencies to source control. You should look at using something like nuget for dependency management. The "dll's in the bin folder" should be recreated from source by building your code.

Comment: Is there a specific NuGet package i need to install as I'm already using it for various features, all that happens when i build the solution is it can't find the files

Comment: I'm fairly new to tfs so if there is a guide or a help hat would be appreciated i haven't managed to find one as of yet

Comment: The nuget package will depend on what you are referencing. Have you told visual Studio to restore packages before you build the solution?

Comment: Are these missed references all managed by nuget? Is there any error when you restore the packages on other machines?  Since you mentioned the dll files in bin folder, are these files generated by the build output of some projects?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click the DLLs that aren't being included, go to Properties, and be sure that the Build Action is set to "Content".

Comment: In that same properties menu, what is your "Copy to Output" set to?

Comment: Do not copy, thats for all of them it seems

Comment: Try doing "Copy To Local"

Comment: That hasn't worked unfortunately, when i get latest on another machine it registers the change but the file still says the item does not exist in project directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you are using MSBuild-Integrated solutions or using Automatic Package Restore. If you use MSBuild-Integrated solutions, [migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore).
2. If you haven't used Nuget to restore package. Check: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore
3. Check whether your project link to other projects. Don't reference output assemblies. Make a project reference or create a NuGet package.